# Is there any evidence whether call centre staff using "air traffic control" spelling of letters helps or hinders understanding?

Tags: telephone

When they say back to you:

"Can you confirm that the first 3 letters of your account / car number plate are

Romeo, X-ray, Alfa" ?

Does this actually help comprehension ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet

Usage relates to call centers speaking to the general public.

Comment: The whole point of the phonetic alphabet existing is to increase understanding (or reduce misunderstanding). Are you talking about call centres *specifically* here? Who are the target audience of these call centres? And are you asking if such audiences actually understand the use of it, or rather - assuming they do understand it - you're just asking if it improves comprehension?

Comment: Edited to add more info.

Comment: _Charlie, Tango, Alpha_ ... are you really spelling things like if you were calling from inside _Full Metal Jacket_ ? Let's hope you don't reach a callcenter in Vietnam or Korea.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling will help (it's its primary purpose) but IMO it should be mandatory only for information that cannot be verified immediately. Why? Because it'll make call longer (something you, usually, want to avoid) and stressing for your users (because, especially if you force them to use NATO Phonetic Alphabet, they don't know it).

For example, if operator ask for last name and fiscal code (as confirmation) then to spell out (using a spelling alphabet) such code is pretty useless (and it'll make users confused and frustrated because procedure will *seem* more complex. Sometimes (but this should be decided case by case, it's not a general rule) spelling will help to prevent mistakes: *"Do you confirm you want to book seat 'Juliet Two'?"*. Single character <kbd>J</kbd> is easily confused with <kbd>G</kbd> (for example).

The right spelling alphabet to pick is not tricky, each nation has its own preferred one:

From [Nations On-line](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/international-spelling-alphabet.htm):

> In many languages the spelling of an alphabet is different and vary greatly.

International **NATO Phonetic Alphabet is probably seldom the best choice** (unless your audience are  *"radio enthusiasts, recreational sailors in the US and Australia, and NATO military organizations"*) because it's an international compromise. Your grandma (if this is your audience) won't understand what you mean with "whiskey" (or she won't even know how to write it). They simply don't know it (because it's commonly used by specific categories) and they'll be really confused (then more error prone). Moreover don't forget that [alphabets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet) are different (both in number and in characters) then international one can't cover them all (in fact it's good for English speakers and acceptable for the others but it covers a very small subset of characters, compare [this very small list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A) with that alphabet).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_alphabet):

> For the general populace, and finance professionals in particular, phonetic alternatives such as "November" for the letter N and "Kilo" for the letter K were considered too long or obscure, and an alternative alphabet arose. Common first names were a popular choice, and as a result the First Name Alphabet (possibly first compiled by a US financial firm) has become quite commonly used.

From [Mike Pope's blog](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wc/do-you-know-your-alfa-bravo-charlies/) about NATO spelling alphabet (emphasis on *learning* is mine):

> For ordinary civilians (like me), **learning** a spelling alphabet has limited applicability in everyday life.

From same article a comment from a bank employee:

> When I use an online banking service and "speak to a representative" I have to verify my identity by naming letters of my password that he or she requests -- e.g., "From your password, Mr. Hargraves, may I have letter number four?" I say the letter and they repeat it back to me in the NATO alphabet above, e.g., "E for echo." This has been going on for so long that I now tell THEM the letter using the spelling alphabet -- to avoid their having to repeat it back to me.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Adriano. The OP asks specifically for evidence.  Do you have any evidence? At the moment, this post reads as only opinion.

Comment: @3nafish thank you! I tried to improve my answer (well some sentences are still only opinions...)

Comment: I don't think we have 'evidence' but the history on the links is interesting.

Comment: @PhillipW yes 'evidence' would require some serious study with pretty big population (to catch all differences) and even in that case it'll be restricted to few countries (for example in Italy if you say "Charlie" for "C" people will look at you like you're mad). IMO in this case we have a - kind of - evidence because of common sense.

Comment: There's lots of info in your post Adriano: I think summarising it, the overall view is "A spelling alphabet is a good idea; but not the NATO" one.  I disagree on the need to study a large population though, if one is just testing it for usage in one country.

Comment: @PhillipW I mean: A spelling alphabet MAY be a good idea if text is not just for verification (for example if you repeat a personal code just to confirm your identity, in that case it's only annoying). If you decide to use it then NATO one is an option but only for a very specific audience (for _normal_ people probably it's not and it may even be confusing). About test on large population: well I mean to see if NATO one is good or not, its acceptance varies according to background, age and many other factors.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one case where the evidence truly is common experiences. Everyone's read letters to others over the phone and has had to resort to "B as in Boy, H as in Hotel..."

In a lot of cases--especially when reading things like serial numbers or license places, there's absolutely no context to place any one letter next to any other. When you are spelling words, there's a bit more context, so the benefit is less, but can still be useful.

As to whether the NATO alphabet is any better/worse, the key is your audience. If you're simply saying "Whisky Tango Foxtrot" it may be lost on many people. But saying "W as in Whisky, T as in Tango, F as in Foxtrot" is fairly clear even if you aren't familiar with the phonetic alphabet. Of course, it's no so much 'Whiskey' that helps but that it's a common word that begins with 'W'.

FYI, if you were in the US Military, you often end up using USAA as your bank the rest of your life. Because this *is* a very particular audience (an audience that had to learn this in training), the support folks at USAA *always* use the NATO alphabet as-is.

Comment: I think the need to clarify is common sense: however the question relates to the best way to do it.  (Although I'd agree with your common sense view of using the "as in XXX" - although using shorter clarification words "W as in Wall" might be easier to understand than "W as in Whisky".

Answer (score 0):

## NATO and The UK

I can only say that here in the UK, with its massive diversity of accents and nationalities, if you prohibit the usage of the NATO system within call centres I can only imagine half of the companies in this country going bankrupted and many call centre personals committing suicide.

I seriously try to recall when was the last time I had a service related phone call where this system wasn't used, whether for my post code (which is nearly a de-facto question for identity-theft/data-protection sake) or my name.

## On Ps and Bs

Anyhow, the cognition aspect behind this are fairly simply - letters like 'b' and 'p' sound very much alike. So much alike that processional singers sing 'B' instead of 'P' as the plosive 'P' causes microphones to pop, where 'B's do not. But listeners don't spot this.

So for the brain it is really hard to decide whether it is B or P without any other hints. It is much (much) easier to distinguish Bravo to Papa.

A visual analogy would be a closeup quiz. Can you tell all body parts in the next collage (notice that for some you consciously have to spend time thinking, and due to ambiguity you may still not be sure):

[image: Various body parts in close up]

[(Answers)](http://www.sporcle.com/games/midlifecrisis/3_letter_parts_close_up/results)